# Xcode switch to IBaction code on click

Tags: xcode, xcode4

In Visual Studio it is possible to select a control on a form and by click on control event switch to the event code. Is it possible to do this in Connections Inspector?

Comment: You can kind of do it the opposite way round. If you open the nib up and code up side by side using the assistance editor, you can hover over the little circle next to a connected action and the control connected to it will be highlighted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to do like Visual Studio.